# imageview пребразовать в bitmap для setLargeIcon(bitmap)

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

С ижу над этой простой задачей уже 3 сутки! испробовал множество вариантов и тестов, а результата ноль...
Суть проста, это приложение чат. Я отправляю сообщение и ему приходит Notification с верху экрана. Все работает.
Я решил установить большую картинку setLargeIcon(bitmap), чтоб было видна аватарка от кого пришло сообщение. И каждый раз когда я отправляю сообщение другому пользователю, у него вылетает приложение.
если использую
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.popoo);
все работает, но это просто картинка. Я же пытаюсь ImageView (Полученную с Firebase) Переделать в bitmap.
Помогите пожалуйста.... Проблему указал прям в коде!

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String sented = remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");
    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String currentUser = preferences.getString("currentuser", "none");

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseUser != null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
        if (!currentUser.equals(user)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage);
            } else {
                sendNotification(remoteMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendOreoNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
         // Data класс имеет правильные значения. iconl как рас ссылка
            на firebase, которая в основном классе работает правильно.
    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
    String iconl = remoteMessage.getData().get("iconl");

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Message_Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("userid", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    // imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.popoo);

    //imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    // Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

// такой же метод я использую чтоб imageview присвоить значение
    сказать с сайта firebase или просто подставить свою из приложения

       // проблема начинается тут ниже!!!
    if (iconl.equals("default")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.popoo);
    } else {
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(iconl).into(imageView);
    }

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
   //проблема заканчивается тут выше...

   // ниже bitmap работает, картинка встает как нужно, но мне нужна картинка ава пользователя кто отправил сообщение
  //  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.popoo);

    OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification(this);
    Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title, body, pendingIntent,
            defaultSound, icon , bitmap);

    int i = 0;
    if (j > 0){
        i = j;
    }

    oreoNotification.getManager().notify(i, builder.build());

}

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
    String iconl = remoteMessage.getData().get("iconl");


    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Message_Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("userid", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

 //   Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(iconl).into(imageView);
  //  BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
  //  Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    //  imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.popoo);
   // imageView.buildDrawingCache();
  //  Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();


    //  BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
   //   Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
          //  .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int i = 0;
    if (j > 0){
        i = j;
    }

    noti.notify(i, builder.build());
        }
     }
```

а это другой класс, он тоже участвует в процессе...

```
public class OreoNotification extends ContextWrapper {

ImageView imageView;

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.koddev.freechat";
private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "freechat";

private NotificationManager notificationManager;

public OreoNotification(Context base) {
    super(base);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        createChannel();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createChannel() {

    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
            CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.enableLights(false);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

    getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

public NotificationManager getManager(){
    if (notificationManager == null){
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    return  notificationManager;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public  Notification.Builder getOreoNotification(String title, String body,
                                                 PendingIntent pendingIntent, Uri soundUri, String icon, Bitmap iconl){


  //  Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(iconl).into(imageView);
 //   BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable();
  //  Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
            .setLargeIcon(iconl)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вы нигде не создаете ImageView.
Во-вторых, он не нужен.
В третьих, Glode загружает картинку асинхронно, сразу bitmap после load вы не получите.

Вам надо сначала получить картинку, и после получения отображать уведомление:

Glide 3

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
    .load(iconl)
    .error(R.drawable.popoo)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            if (errorDrawable instance of BitmapDrawable) {
                 Bitmap errorBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)errorDrawable).getBitmap();
                 sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage, errorBitmap);
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage, resource);
        }
    });
```

**upd** для Glide 4.x

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(iconl)
            .addListener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Bitmap errorBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.popoo)).getBitmap();
                    sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage, errorBitmap);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage, resource);
                    return true;
                }
            }).preload();
```

Comment: не получается( R.drawable.popoo) подчеркивается красным.  if (errorDrawable instace of BitmapDrawable) , это тоже. .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() пишет что нужно имплементить другой метод

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо мой код для 3-го glide, для 4-й версии должно быть аналогично, за исключением сигнатуры методов... Чуть позже посмотрю, обновлю ответ.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Попробуйте.